Sidekiq reserved queues are not respected when running specific queues on separate Heroku dynos/ machines
Info:

Ruby version: 3.1.4
Rails version: 6.1.7.6
Sidekiq / Pro / Enterprise version(s): Free 6.5.12

Problem:
When I use the reserved queues settings https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#reserved-queues  (1 queue per 1 Heroku dyno), I could still see the dyno worker (say for queue A) processing the job of another queue B (that's supposed to be processed on another dyno).
Heroku Procfile, each line is a seprate machine/ dyno
app_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -t 25 -c 10 -q default,1 -q images_processing,1
critical_worker: IS_SCHEDULER=true bundle exec sidekiq -t 25 -c 10 -q critical,1 -q mailers,1
init_caching_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -t 25 -c 10 -q caching_integration_bookings

This is what the Sidekiq UI shows the workers:

This is what the Sidekiq UI shows the jobs running:

Expected: The app_worker is NOT supposed to process jobs on the caching_integration_bookings queue.
Here's the config/initializers/sidekiq.yml
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-scheduler'

# Sidekiq-Cron is checking jobs to be enqueued every 10 seconds
Sidekiq::Options[:cron_poll_interval] = 10

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: ENV['REDIS_URL'],
    ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
  }
  config.on(:startup) do
    scheduler_file = ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'production' ? '../sidekiq_production_scheduler.yml' : '../sidekiq_non_prod_scheduler.yml'
    Rails.logger.info("Loading sidekiq schedule file: #{scheduler_file}")
    Sidekiq.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path(scheduler_file, __dir__))
    SidekiqScheduler::Scheduler.instance.reload_schedule!
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: ENV['REDIS_URL'],
    ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
  }
end


